# how to continue scraping even with error msg

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am running my web scraping script which gathers thousands of data. The problem is it keeps stopping when there is an error . I want it just log the error and continue to the next url. Here is what I currently have in regards to exception

```
uClient3 = ''
while uClient3 == '':
    try:
       uClient3 = requests.get(fsgsubcard2ref)
       print("Proceding to the next level in...")

    except:
        print("Connection refused by the server..")
        print("Let me sleep for 7 seconds")
        print("ZZzzzz...")
        time.sleep(8)
        print("Was a nice sleep, now let me continue...")

        continue
```

how can I prevent the error from stopping the script and logging it ?

Comment: Your code is horribly indented. Where does the `continue` statement belong? Is `except` indeed indented the way you posted it?

Comment: And add the stack trace of your error.

Comment: Is this a [mcve]? Your try statement shouldn't exit the loop

Comment: i have fixed the indentation

Answer (score -1):

After `uClient3 = requests.get(fsgsubcard2ref)`, `uClient3` will be store `Response` object, and your conditions `while uClient3 == ''` will return `False`. The best way from my side is using for-loop:

```
for i in fsgsubcard2ref: # fsgsubcard2ref should be a list() with all url, or you can can use variable with another name
    try:
        response = requests.get(i)
        # processing
    except:
        print('Error')
```

Comment: @DYZ `requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com')` return `Response` object, not `str`. And `while uClient3 == ''` everytime will be `False`, because of `Response != ''`

Comment: fsgsubcars2ref appears to be a url.  So you will be making an HTTP request for every character in the url which will fail every time and print Error.

Comment: I added comment that `fsgsubcard2ref` should be a list with all url